# How can I display the year for different kinds of groups using Twig?

Tags: date, twig

I have several "types" of data. For example, let's say I am tracking how much corn I have harvested for each field, and how much soybeans I have harvested for each field.

I am able to collect all of the data I need - all is well. It's getting the data out that I'm stumbling a bit.

I would like to group my data by growing season (year). What is throwing me is that I may not always have data for corn or I may not always have data for soybeans.

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this. Each season (year) is grouped together, but showing all the data for each type...

**html**

```
<h3>2016 Season</h3>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Harvest Date</th>
        <th>Corn</th>
        <th>Soybeans</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>2016-06-12</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>300</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>

<h3>2015 Season</h3>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Harvest Date</th>
        <th>Corn</th>
        <th>Soybeans</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>2015-06-10</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>400</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what I am doing currently which is about 80% close.

**twig**

```
{% if myData.soybeans|length %}
    {% for year, crops in myData.soybeans|group('harvest_date|date("Y")') %}
    <h3>2016 Soybeans</h3>
    <table>
    ...
{% endfor %}


{% if myData.corn|length %}
    {% for year, crops in myData.corn|group('harvest_date|date("Y")') %}
    <h3>2016 Corn</h3>
    <table>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Which works great if I want to show the year, and then list each crop type below it in separate tables. I'd like to show all crop types in the same table. But, what If I don't have one or the other? What should I use to look for a date to group by?

Comment: I'll suggest you to group them on the server side.

Comment: Hi Veve - If you update your suggestion as the answer, I'll accept it - then revise my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done on the server side.

It could be done with Twig but in a good architecture it's not its role.